# Convert European currency format to US

Tags: xslt

I have got data, wherein one of the columns has pricing info in European format.

```
<column_10>1,74</column_10>
```

How can I convert 1,74 to 1.74? I've tried the below code, but it doesn't work.

```
<xsl:value-of select="(translate('column_10', ',', '.'))" />
```

Thanks

Comment: "below code" - I'm not seeing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote the element name: `<xsl:value-of select="translate(column_10, ',', '.')" />`
`